# Where clause and its order during join Operation

Tags: sql, oracle

Was asked in an interview a traditional question of self join with manager and employee.

I was confused as interviewer asked me to display the columns as EmployeeName, Manager Name.

Please advice how does the conditions in where clause effects the selected columns. As I wasn't able to get the required order.

[image: TABLE Contents]

Comment: *the conditions in where clause...* what conditions in what where clause?

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt, but... with your level of knowledge, were you interviewing for a **job** that requires writing queries? Let's leave aside how easy this problem is (one shouldn't pass the first midterm in the first intro class if they are confused by this, much less get a job in the industry). What do you mean by "condition in `where` clause [a]ffects the selected columns"? Nothing in the `where` clause affects the columns in `select`. It may affect what **rows** are selected, but nothing about the **columns**. My sincere advice: before applying for other jobs like this, learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that every manager is also an employee, so you can join the table on itself, and use one side of the join for the employee details and the other for the manager's details:

```sql
SELECT e.eployee_name AS "employee name", m.employee_name AS "manager name"
FROM   employee e
JOIN   employee m ON e.manager_id = m.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `connect by` query as following:

```
select employee_name, prior employee_name
  from employees
connect by prior employee_id  = manager_id
start with manager_id is null
```

If you want to use join then you must do `outer join` as following:

```
Select e.employee_name, m.employee_name
  From employees e left join employees m
On e.employee_id = m.employee_id
```

`Left outer join` will make sure that all the employees will exists in the result as the employee who is the top manager will have null `manager_id` and `inner join` will exclude that employee from the result.

Cheers!!